# Corda notary ClassNotFoundException : Malformed transaction, OUTPUTS_GROUP at index 0 cannot be deserialised

Tags: kotlin, classloader, corda

When running an InitiatingFlow/InitiatedBy between two nodes, my notary node threw an error: `java.lang.Exception: Malformed transaction, OUTPUTS_GROUP at index 0 cannot be deserialised`
And a bit further down the trace: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: xxx.xxx.xxx.shared.states.OrderItemState`

Including the 'shared' CordApp where this state was defined in my notary fixes the issue, but I don't understand why this is necessary?

I was able to send other states back and forth between the nodes just fine without including that CordApp
Only difference is that the `OrderItemState` is a `LinearState` where the other ones were `FungibleAsset`,  am I to look for an answer there?

Comment: Is it a validating or non-validating notary? (either way, this sounds strange). Is this something you would be able to check into github for us to take a look at?

Comment: Unfortunately not able to share, sorry...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're using a validating notary. A validating notary is one that checks that the transaction is valid, as well as checking that it does not contain a double-spend attempt. This has a cost in terms of privacy. See https://docs.corda.net/key-concepts-notaries.html#validation.

If you look at the code that sends the transaction to the notary in `NotaryFlow.Client`, you can see that a validating notary is sent the entire transaction, and therefore needs the CorDapp defining the involved states in its `cordapps` folder:

```
if (serviceHub.networkMapCache.isValidatingNotary(notaryParty)) {
    subFlow(SendTransactionWithRetry(session, stx))
    session.receive<List<TransactionSignature>>()
}
```

Comment: Thanks Joel, it is indeed a validating notary. I understand that the transaction is resent, but then why does this error not occur for states extending `FungibleAsset`? Does this have anything to do with the list of participants, which for my `FungibleAsset` states is limited to the owner of the state?

Comment: A transaction will only be sent to the notary if it has either input states and/or a timewindow. Perhaps in the `FungibleAsset` case, neither of these conditions are met?

Comment: No, there are inputStates present when we are moving the `FungibleAsset` states from nodeA to nodeB, and the (validating) notary is used in the `TransactionBuilder` constructor. We are executing this move using `OnLedgerAsset.generateSpend` if that can help shed some light on the issue?

Comment: Sorry, I'd have to see the actual CorDapp. Are you using one of the fungible states defined in the Finance CorDapp?

Comment: No, we're extending the `FungibleAsset` in a custom state of our own. I'll see what I can do about disclosing more information..

Comment: Thanks. If you can replicate with a minimal example, that would be awesome :)